# How to prove that $16^n+25^n+36^n$ isn't divisible by $15$

Tags: calculus, induction

I get to the point where I need to prove it for n=n+1, I know how to prove that something is divisible by something, but I don't have the idea how to prove that something is....

Comment: These types of problems tend to not work well with induction. Instead, maybe try proving its either not divisible by $3$, or not divisible by $5$?

Comment: yea proving something **is** divisible by something would have been much easier with induction. But it's also possible that it can work.

Comment: It is, in fact, always relative prime to $15.$

Comment: Consider separately divisibility by $3$ and $5$, and reduce modulo $3$ and $5$ respectively: it simplifies nicely.

Comment: It is easier to prove it is never divisible by $3.$ You can do this by proving $1+$ this value is always divisible by $3.$

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $36  = 6 \mod 15$ and $6^2  = 6 \mod 15$, i.e., all positive powers of $36$ are congruent to $6 \mod 15$. Similarly $25 = 10 \mod 15$ and $10^2 =100 = 10 \mod 15$. Lasly, $16  = 1 \mod 15$, so that
$$  16^n + 25^n + 36^n = 1 + 10 +6 \mod 15.  $$

Comment: Except for $n=0$. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Quite right